# Only finding first match in CSV file

Tags: python, csv, file

I have a script that reads a CSV file 'friends_req.csv' and checks if a specific user exists in the file. If the user exists, it prints "You have friend request", otherwise it prints "No request found for this user". However, when there are multiple requests for the same user, the script only prints the first request but not the others. I need to print all requests on separate lines. But I don't know how to make it.

This is my code

```
def get_request(user):
    if not os.path.exists('friends_req.csv'):
        open('friends_req.csv','w').close()
    with open('friends_req.csv','r+') as d:
        reader = csv.reader(d)
        for row in reader:
            if row[1] == user:
                print(f'You have a friend request from {row[0]}')
                return row[0]
    print("No request found for this user")
```

And this is my CSV file

```
u,user
g,user
```

It only prints 'you have friend request from u', but it must print 'you have friend request from u' and on another line 'you have friend request from g'

Comment: Don't `return row[0]` if you want to continue to iterate.

Comment: Why are you creating the file if it doesn't exist? Why, if it does exist, are you opening in 'r+'?

Comment: Your `return` command ends the loop (and the whole function actually) after the first print. If you need to finally return the user then save it to some local variable and return it after the loop ends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store results in a variable:

```
def get_request(user):
    with open('friends_req.csv') as d:
        reader = csv.reader(d)
        results = [row[0] for row in reader if row[1] == user]
        if results:
            print(f'You have friends request from {", ".join(results)}')
        else:
            print("No request found for this user")
        return results
```

Output:

```
>>> res = get_request('user')
You have friends request from u, g

>>> res
['u', 'g']
```

`friends_req.csv`:

```
u,user
g,user
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
def get_request(user):
    if not os.path.exists('friends_req.csv'):
        open('friends_req.csv','w').close()
    requests = []
    with open('friends_req.csv','r+') as d:
        reader = csv.reader(d)
        for row in reader:
            if row[1] == user:
                requests.append(row[0])
    if len(requests) > 0:
        for request in requests:
            print(f'You have a friend request from {request}')
    else:
        print("No request found for this user")
```

Comment: Your indentation is flawed

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the *csv* module for something so trivial. Just do this:

```
FILENAME = 'friends_req.csv'

def get_request(filename, user):
    requests = []
    try:
        with open(filename) as data:
            for line in map(str.strip, data):
                f, u = line.split(',')
                if u == user:
                    requests.append(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
    return requests

print(get_request(FILENAME, 'user'))
```